# Antisymmetric components in Gaussian kernel

Tags: covariance-matrix

In Bishop's *Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning*, he states on page 80 in reference to the squared Mahalanobis distance $(\mathbf{x} - \boldsymbol{\mu})^\top\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1}(\mathbf{x} - \boldsymbol{\mu})$ that:

> the matrix $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}$ can be taken to be symmetric,
>   without loss of generality, because any antisymmetric component would
>   disappear from the exponent.

My understanding was that all covariance matrices must be symmetric, so could someone please explain what this statement means?

Comment: But why "must" they be symmetric? Bishop defined multivariate Gaussian distribution on page 78 with an arbitrary matrix $\boldsymbol \Sigma$. This remark is to say that it can as well be taken to be symmetric. Because $\mathbf a^\top \mathbf B\mathbf a=0$ for any antisymmetric $\mathbf B$.

Answer (score 2):

write (2.44) as $\Delta^2 = (x-\mu)^T A (x-\mu)$, where $A = \Sigma^{-1}$.

We know that $A = \frac{1}{2} (A + A^T) + \frac{1}{2} (A - A^T)$. Let $B = \frac{1}{2} (A + A^T), C = \frac{1}{2} (A - A^T)$, then $B$ is symmetric, and $C$ is anti-symmetric, $c_{ij} = - c_{ji}$.

So $\Delta^2 = (x-\mu)^T B (x-\mu) + (x-\mu)^T C (x-\mu)$, in which $(x-\mu)^T C (x-\mu) = \sum_{i=1}^D \sum_{j=1}^D c_{ij} (x-\mu)_i (x-\mu)_j = \sum_{i=1}^D\sum_{j=i+1}^D (c_{ij}+c_{ji}) (x-\mu)_i (x-\mu)_j = 0$.

So $\Delta^2 = (x-\mu)^T B (x-\mu)$, where $B = \frac{1}{2} (A + A^T)$ is a symmetric matrix. That is, if $\Sigma^{-1}$ isn't symmetric, then there's another symmetric matrix $B$ so that $\Delta^2 = (x-\mu)^T \Sigma^{-1} (x-\mu)$ is equal to $\Delta^2 = (x-\mu)^T B (x-\mu)$.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, a covariance matrix $\Sigma$ is symmetric (positive semidefinite).

Perhaps, the author refers to the concept of multivariate symmetry.
A *spherical* symmetric multivariate distribution is for example a multivariate normal with covariance $\Sigma = \sigma I$. *Elliptical* symmetry is what is assumed by the Mahalanobis distance, allowing for a covariance matrix $\Sigma$ with the properties you are assuming and with a characteristic function as defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptical_distribution)

Now, if your multinomial distribution is characterized by some [anti-symmetric properties](http://www.utdallas.edu/~serfling/papers/ess2.pdf) (f.ex skewness and kurtosis), those properties will not be captured by the Mahalanobis norm.